# Sum of multi indexed columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is my example dataframe in pandas. It is a pivot table.:

```
       High School                       Middle School                
Year   Teachers Students COA         Teachers Students COA  
2019      40   500      3000           30       200     1000
2018      70   1000     5000           50       400     1500
```

I want to add three new columns called "Total teachers", "total students" and "total COA". The resulting df should look like this:

```
            High School               Middle School                 
    Year   Teachers Students COA      Teachers Students COA     Total_Teachers Total_students Total_COA  
    2019      40   500      3000      30       200     1000      70             700           4000
    2018      70   1000     5000      50       400     1500      120            1400          6500
```

I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: This is just an example I made to replicate my original dataframe which is very huge, can't post that output of my original df.to_dict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do a sum:

```
df['High School']+df['Middle School']
```

output:

```
      Teachers  Students   COA
Year                          
0           70       700  4000
1          120      1400  6500
```

Regarding the final table, I recommend this format:

```
     High School                Middle School                   Total               
        Teachers Students   COA      Teachers Students   COA Teachers Students   COA
Year                                                                                
0             40      500  3000            30      200  1000       70      700  4000
1             70     1000  5000            50      400  1500      120     1400  6500
```

You can get it using:

```
df2 = pd.concat({'Total': df['High School']+df['Middle School']}, axis=1)
pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)
```

If you insist on the given output format:

```
pd.concat([df,
           pd.concat({'': (df['High School']+df['Middle School']).add_prefix('Total_')}, axis=1)
           ], axis=1)
```

output:

```
     High School                Middle School                                                       
        Teachers Students   COA      Teachers Students   COA Total_Teachers Total_Students Total_COA
Year                                                                                                
0             40      500  3000            30      200  1000             70            700      4000
1             70     1000  5000            50      400  1500            120           1400      6500
```

Comment: That's how you would do it without multiindex ;) let's not be afraid of multiindexes :D

Answer (score 1):

Filter columns that contain 'School' then group by the second level of column index and sum each sub column. Add a first level 'Total' to output using `pd.concat`and finally merge it with your original dataframe.

```
out = pd.concat({'Total': df.filter(like='School')
                            .groupby(level=1, sort=False, axis=1)
                            .sum()}, axis=1)
```

```
>>> out
     Total
  Teachers Students   COA
0       70      700  4000
1      120     1400  6500

>>> pd.concat([df, out], axis=1)
        High School                Middle School                   Total
   Year    Teachers Students   COA      Teachers Students   COA Teachers Students   COA
0  2019          40      500  3000            30      200  1000       70      700  4000
1  2018          70     1000  5000            50      400  1500      120     1400  6500
```